How to Calculate the Shadow Area Cast by One Object on Another in Blender Using Sunlight?
I have a scene in Blender with two cube objects and a sunlight source. I would like to calculate the shadow area cast by the first cube (Object 1) onto a specific face of the second cube (Object 2), considering the sunlight direction. The cubes are positioned in such a way that Object 1 casts a shadow on Object 2.
Can anyone guide me on how to calculate the shadow area cast from Object 1 onto a specific face of Object 2 when lit by the Sunlight?
I’m open to any Python methods, tools, or ideas that can help achieve this.
Thank you!

Assuming manifold geometry, you can elongate the shadow caster(s), and find their boolean mesh intersection with shadow receivers. Then find the surface to the front of the Sun, which you can simply by comparing the dot product of sun direction and face normal. What I do is find the part cut through the receiver, delete it, then use blurred normal (I actually blur selection but I think I could blur the normal) select and remove the backside as well. Now use an Attribute Statistic on what's left.

Imgur mirror (SE image hosting has problems)

